# Merge possibly truncated gzipped log files

Tags: gzip, corruption

I have multiple log files from each day that I need to merge together. Each comes from a different server.   The job that puts them there sometimes gets interrupted and files get truncated.   In that case the file gets written with a different name next time it runs.   So I may end up with a list of log files like:

- `server-1-log.gz` (Yesterday's log file)
- `server-1-log.1.gz` (Today's log file that got interrupted while transferring and is truncated)
- `server-1-log.2.gz` (Today's log file re-transferred and intact)
- `server-2-log.gz` (Yesterday's log file)
- `server-2-log.1.gz` (Today's log file)

All the log files start with a time stamp on each line, so it is fairly trivial to sort and de-duplicate them.   I've been trying to merge these files using the command:

```
zcat *.gz | sort | uniq | gzip > /tmp/merged.gz
```

The problem is that the truncated log file produces the following error from `zcat`:

> gzip: server-1-log.1.gz: unexpected end of file

It turns out that zcat completely exits when it hits this error, without reading all the data from the other files.      I end up losing the data that exists in the other good files because one of the files is corrupt.    How can I fix this?

- Can I tell `zcat` not to exit on errors?  I don't see anything in the man page for it.
- Can I fix truncated gzip files before calling `zcat`?
- Can I use a different decompression program instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m guessing you’re using the `gzip` script version of `zcat`. That just executes `gzip -dc`, which can’t be told to ignore errors and stops when it encounters one.

The documented fix for individual corrupted compressed files is to run them through `zcat`, so you won’t get much help there...

To process your files, you can either loop over them (with a `for` loop or `xargs` as you found), or use [Zutils](http://www.nongnu.org/zutils/zutils.html) which has a version of `zcat` which continues processing when it encounters errors.

Comment: Is the "continue processing on errors" from zutils standard, or does it need a command line argument for it?

Comment: It’s the default behaviour, at least for `zcat`.

Comment: Thanks.  zutils just got installed on all my servers.   Seems like a nice package with significant functionality over the standard stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it.   I can run each file through its own instance of `zcat`.  To do so, I can use `xargs -n 1` to start an instance of zcat for each file:

```
echo *.gz | xargs -n 1 zcat | sort | uniq | gzip > /tmp/merged.gz
```

The single zcat still fails, but the other ones run to completion.   It doesn't kill the whole pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Try [*Super Speedy Syslog Searcher*](https://crates.io/crates/super_speedy_syslog_searcher)

(assuming you have [rust installed](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install))

```
cargo install super_speedy_syslog_searcher
```

then

```
s4 server-*.gz
```

`s4` can read `.gz` files.